# Matching valid alternative in SKIP-FAIL regex

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, pcre, skip

I have a working regex:

```
~<([A-Za-z_\-]+)[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]|^|\n)text([A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]|$|\n)~sig
```

Now, I want to match `wanna_match_this` in `<blockquote>wanna_match_this</blockquote>` and I am trying to [fix this](https://regex101.com/r/hF8kJ8/1):

```
<([A-Za-z_\-]+)[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]|^|\n)wanna_match_this([A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]|$|\n)
```

It should match `wanna_match_this` in `<blockquote>wanna_match_this</blockquote>`, but it does not.

[This one matches](https://regex101.com/r/sX7dJ8/1) but I need the other one that is more precise.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I have a problem, not a question. The only question is if anyone can help me fixing it?

Comment: What is the problem? Describe the problem rather that providing regex101 links

Comment: I've written "wanna_match_this" in regex101 links. Isn't the problem clear enough?

Comment: No it's not. Please include all the relevant information in your question on this site, not in external links.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact the first alternative (with SKIP-FAIL) consumes any `<TAG>` and proceeds searching for a match right *after* the end of the unsuccessfully matched text. The `wanna_match_this` text starts right after that text and `[A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]` consumes the `w` char preventing this match from occurring.

So, you need a *zero-width asertion*, a positive lookbehind here, best coupled with 
 a positive lookahead:

```
<([A-Za-z_-]+)[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=[A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]|^)wanna_match_this(?=[A-Za-z0-9<>:\[\]\s]|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xE1qQJ/1)

Notice I removed `\n` as it is already covered with `\s`.